# Firebase hosting does not send custom HTTP headers

Tags: firebase, firebase-hosting, firebase-cli

According to [Firebase Hosting docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/full-config#headers), I should be able to set custom headers on responses received from the server. I am trying to set the `X-Frame-Options` header on all html files, but the server simply does not want to send this header! Here's my firebase.json file, please let me know if I am doing anything wrong:

```
{
  "hosting": {
    "public": "build",
    "ignore": [
      "firebase.json",
      "**/.*",
      "**/node_modules/**"
    ],
    "headers": [
      {
        "source": "**/*.html",
        "headers": [
          {
            "key": "X-Frame-Options",
            "value": "SAMEORIGIN"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After lot of trial and error, I found the issue. All this while I was trying to load index.html using `https://my-project.firebaseapp.com` - this apparently does not trigger the header. I had to explicitly add `/index.html` at the end of the URL to make it work: `https://my-project.firebaseapp.com/index.html`. I should not have to do this, but that was the problem. So the question still remains - how do you get the firebase configuration to match an implied `index.html`.

Answer (score 6):

I just went through a lot of trial and error on the same issue.  I noticed a small little section in the [firebase documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/full-config):

> A source value that Hosting matches against the original request path, *regardless of any rewrite rules*.

If your setup is like mine, you probably have this in your firebase.json file:

```
  "rewrites": [{
    "source": "**",
    "destination": "/index.html"
  }]
```

However, while you may be returning index.html, the original request path was simply "/", so on your headers section use this:

```
"source": "/"
```

This is what worked for me.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. Although I am not using this project anymore, this will be helpful in the future.